# Animating Along Curved Motion Path Using Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

I'm currently trying to do a bit of an experiment with Canvas, it's one of my first forays into using it. The linked CodePen is some brilliant code from another user that I've forked to create something in the style I needed.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/utgvb

The functionality I'm trying to create is that of the line animating in a loop **until** a mousemove within the canvas element. My thoughts were to use Math.random() to generate numbers for each x and y co-ordinate but I'm having trouble figuring out the logic. I want to make it as graceful and code-light as possible which means utilising much of the existing code - however only having a 70% accurate grasp of how the code is running is hampering my progress.

I thought a function that works similar to this one that's already in use could be created:

```
function update() {

  target.x += (mouse.x - target.x);
  target.y += (mouse.y - target.y);

  chain.update( target );
}
```

I believe this function is key to making the line follow the cursor, so my thinking was to create a function that accessed the properties of an array of objects, each containing "x: foo, y: bar" in a loop, thus moving the line to those co-ordinates one after the other. I have a feeling however, there may be a far simpler solution staring me in the face.

Does any one have any pointers?

Comment: so the functionality is while the mouse is not moving to have the blue line spin in a circle around the mouse?

Comment: It could be movement to random co-ordinates or (probably more sensibly) on a set path of pre-defined co-ordinates, sorry that was so unclear in my post, total brain dump!

Comment: The mouse move event is setting the mouse.x and mouse.y which is then used by update(). So to override the method like you want you just need a new loop updating the mouse object I think, and a robust way of swapping between the mouse move event method and the new loop

Comment: I managed to fix this last night - http://codepen.io/williamrenwick/pen/xlhjb

Comment: However, as usual I've decided I would like a little more than just a circular motion, perhaps a figure of 8, I'm wondering if the only way to do that is using a beizer curve and setting 8 x,y positions for it to move around?

Answer (score 0):

Just for transparency I'll post the code I added to create the animation, with thanks to nepeo for the advice:

```
function animLoop() {

  var speed = 5,    
      rad = (degree * Math.PI / 180);

  degree += 1;  

  mouse.x += speed * Math.sin(rad);
  mouse.y += speed * Math.cos(rad);

  //reset degrees
  if (degree == 360) {
      degree = 0;
  }
}
```

If anyone needs more info on animating along curves in Canvas I recommend starting here:

http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001654/ch05.html#uniform_circular_motion

It's really comprehensive and helps you understand exactly what it is you're doing with the mathematics rather than just giving you the solution.